# EOFError: EOF when reading a line - in tic-tae-toe - Python

Tags: python, eoferror

during tests it's showing the error message:

---

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "tictactoe/tictactoe.py", line 10, in <module>
       coordinates = input("Enter the coordinates: ")
   EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

---

I can't image what is causing this problem. The code is:

```
c = True
while c:
  coordinates = input("Enter the coordinates: ")  # <-- line 10 is this one
  if coordinates == '':
    print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
    continue
  elif len(coordinates) < 3 or len(coordinates) > 3:
    print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
    continue
```

Thanks for support

Comment: The only way I can replicate this is by passing `EOF` (`CTRL` + `D`) to `input`. Is it what you're sending in to stdin that's causing this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce the error based on the code provided. The loop runs without error. Is there more code that you haven't included, or is your code slightly different in your question than in the script?

Comment: The error message is from the automatic test, which unfortunately I'm not informed about. Is there a way to solve CTRL+D?

Comment: Without knowing what the test is doing, it's going to be pretty difficult to solve this problem. Is the test designed to send data to the program? Is there any detail at all surrounding the test?

Comment: The user is supposed to input 2 numbers (coordinates) in order to play the game. The rest of the code deals with interpreting and drawing the playing board.

Comment: How is the test written? That's the real question.

Comment: Is it possible in if statement to consider CTRL+D and continue prompting the player enter the numbers?

Comment: unfortunately the test is not viewable.

Comment: We would need to know if there's even `stdin` available to whatever is running the test

Comment: As it sits, I'm voting to close as it's going to be almost impossible to give you a proper solution without additional detail. Hopefully you can find out more about the test that's being run, if you do, please update this question so we can help you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Your test probably runs the code non-interactively. If you are creating the test in Python, try using subprocess.PIPE so that you can communicate with the subprocess. Without a valid stdin, the program will throw this error, which (should) cause your test to fail.